# How to disable a TKinter scrollbar widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a single thread program with a GUI, which executes a series of tasks. During these tasks the GUI is refreshed regularly to check for a few available inputs (e.g. abort). To avoid halting the task with unwanted inputs all unnecessary GUI elements are disabled by `.config(state='disabled')` during execution.
This however does not seem work for scrollbars which for some reason are unique and don't have a `"-state"` option.

Comment: You might be able to disable the `Scrollbar` by temporarily configuring its `command` option to be `None` (or perhaps `lambda *a: None` so the normal callback isn't called.

Comment: On windows setting the `command` to `None` does not disable the `Scrollbar`. However setting it to an empty string, i.e. `command=""` does work.

Comment: Setting `command=""` does not solve the problem completely. Since the `Scrollbar` remains active the main task will be halted for as long as it is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't disable the scrollbar widget using the `-state` option, I've searched in the [Tcl/Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scrollbar.htm) website and I didn't find anything about it.

But I am sure you can use the [pack_forget()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method) method to delete it from the window if you are using the [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) geometry or the [grid_forget()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method) if you are using the [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) geometry, so you can later show the scrollbar widget again calling `pack/grid` again.

Here's a example:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

def disable_scroll():
    scrollbar.pack_forget()

def active_scroll():
    scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command=None)

btn1 = Button(master, text="OK 1", command=disable_scroll)
btn1.pack()

btn2 = Button(master, text="OK 2", command=active_scroll)
btn2.pack()


listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))

listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

The Scrollbar changes according the Listbox's values, so as I said here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

def disable_scroll():
    scrollbar.pack_forget()

def active_scroll():
    scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command=None)

btn1 = Button(master, text="disable_scroll", command=disable_scroll)
btn1.pack()

btn2 = Button(master, text="active_scroll", command=active_scroll)
btn2.pack()

listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#NEW FUNCTIONS
def count():
    listbox.delete(0, END)

    lista = [5, 8, 500, 1000]
    for i in range(random.choice(lista)):
        listbox.insert(END, str(i))

def delete():
    listbox.delete(0, END)

#NEW BUTTONS
btn3 = Button(master, text="start", command=count)
btn3.pack()

btn4 = Button(master, text="delete", command=delete)
btn4.pack()

listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You. This gets the job done. For my case there has to be a `master.update()` in `disable_scroll()` and `enable_scroll()` to ensure the scrollbar changes immediately on exectuion of the methods.

Comment: You're welcome! I've done a little test and I realized that the scrollbar updates automatic.

Comment: In this example it makes no difference. If disableing and enableing is called as part of another method and stuff happens in between it becomes an issue

Comment: I've added a couple buttons that add items and clear them in the Listbox, so when I use the buttons the scrollbar updates automatic, I'll post the complete code to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach to get the scroll bar to display with a disabled look (instead of being hidden) is to:

1. Remove all entries in the list (the scroll bar will become disabled)
2. Detach the scroll bar from the list
3. Re-insert the removed entries with the scroll bar detached (the scroll bar will remain disabled)

In the code below, 'listbox' is my tk.Listbox object,'scrollbar' is the associated 'tk.Scrollbar' object, and self is a reference to the parent object. Code tested on Window with Python 3.8.4rc1.

Disable code:

```
entries = listbox.get(0, "end")
listbox.delete(0, "end")
self.update()
listbox.config(yscrollcommand="")
scrollbar.config(command="")
listbox.insert("end", *entries)
listbox['state'] = "disabled"
```

Enable code:

```
listbox['state'] = "normal"
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
```

Comment: Note that this code will not preserve selections or the horizontal/vertical scrolling positions since the elements are removed and re-added. Upon request, I can post a full code of enable/disable functions which preserve all aspects, and keep items highlighted (grayed out) when the control is disabled.