# Remove tkinter combobox scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Is there any way to remove the scrollbar of a `Combobox` or to change its width? I mean the scrollbar that appears automatically when you have multiple items in `Combobox` list.

Comment: Why don't use `Listbox` directly?

Comment: I think this post might help you along:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499836/how-to-disable-a-tkinter-scrollbar-widget